# Should I use select_for_update in my django application with postgresql database?

Tags: django, postgresql

I am currently building a booking tool (django and postgresql) where people book spaces in a location. The location has limited capacity and therefore might run out of space while a user is trying to book a space. I imagine that this could happen when another user books a place slightly before the current user is booking, e.g. if only 1 space is left, the other user might book too and the database cannot handle it.

So my question is would you strongly advise using select_for_update or is there something else that might help me overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a correct use of `select_for_update`. You would be blocking a specific location row (apply a `filter` before calling `select_for_update`). That means that 2 different locations can be booked concurrently, but if there are 2 bookings for the same location happening at exactly the same second they would be called.

This creates a *critical section* and you can sure that it won't overlap with a critical section of another request. In within the critical section, you will have to validate that the selected time slot is free - without that validation `select_for_update` would have no effect.

I could imagine another approach based on unique constraints, it's not universal but might be easier to implement. Let's imagine that you are booking a resource for a specific day. You could have a "unique together" combination for the `resource_id` and `date`. A subsequent save would raise an `IntegrityError` and you could catch it and inform the user that the resource was just booked for the selected date.

Comment: Thank you so much @Snake9920 when I use `select_for_update` on one table is it only locking this one, or also all other tables in the database?

Comment: It is locking specific rows (the ones you selected) rather than entire tables. I'd recommend to read more about it in the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) as Django is simply adding the "FOR UPDATE" clause to the SQL query and the database engine is doing the actual locking.